# How to put default value in CJuidatepicker in Yii?

Tags: jquery-ui, yii, jquery-ui-datepicker, zii-widgets, yii-widgets

I have the code below to display a calendar input in Yii form.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                'name' => 'publish_date',
                'attribute' => 'publish_date',
                'model'=>$model,
                'options'=> array(
                  'dateFormat' =>'yy-mm-dd',
                  'defaultDate' => '2014-3-4',
                  'altFormat' =>'yy-mm-dd',
                  'changeMonth' => true,
                  'changeYear' => true,
                  'appendText' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                ),  
              )); 
 ?>
```

The default value work on the calendar but I want to show it by default in the calendar input too when the form is rendering.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Html value attribute for this

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                'name' => 'publish_date',
                'attribute' => 'publish_date',
                'model'=>$model,
                'options'=> array(
                  'dateFormat' =>'yy-mm-dd',
                  'defaultDate' => '2014-3-4',
                  'altFormat' =>'yy-mm-dd',
                  'changeMonth' => true,
                  'changeYear' => true,
                  'appendText' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                ),
               'htmlOptions'=>array('value'=>'2013-4-4')
              ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Manquer's solution didn't work (in version 1.1.17), `CJuiDatePicker` extends from `CJuiInputWidget` and it has a `value` property which is used by `CHtml::inputField()` when rendering the element, overwriting the `value` field of `htmlOptions` property.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'name' => 'publish_date',
    'attribute' => 'publish_date',
    'model'=>$model,
    'options'=> array(
        'dateFormat' =>'yy-mm-dd',
        'defaultDate' => '2014-3-4',
        'altFormat' =>'yy-mm-dd',
        'changeMonth' => true,
        'changeYear' => true,
        'appendText' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    ),
    'value' => '2013-3-4',
));
```

Comment: Manquer's solution didn't work for me. But szako's did.