# How can I change the default value of date to null in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

Do I need any change in the below code to get the Default value of DATE as NULL ?
I have tried in the database, there I changed the constraint default to null, but I didn't find any solution.
Would you please give me a solution ?

```
<?php 
        // $model->confirmation_dt ='03/03/2011';  // default date
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => "confirmation_dt",
        'options'   => array(
            'dateFormat' => Yii::app()->params['dateFmtDP'],
            'yearRange'  => '1900:c+10',
            'changeYear' => true
        ),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'size' => '10',         // textField size
            'maxlength' => '10',    // textField maxlength
            // 'value' => '03/03/2011', // Alternate method for default date
            // 'value' => date('d/m/Y'), // set the default date as today's date
            // 'value' => NUll, // set the default date here // This one is not working
        ),
    )); ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe try `value` attribute outside `htmlOptions` like there https://stackoverflow.com/a/45649715/6350167

Comment: The default value inside `htmlOptions` is used to populate the input with the date you set. This will not do this for the database, you should add it as a rule in your model file.

Comment: You can find out [all about rules and validation](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/reference-model-rules-validation?revision=16#how-validation-works) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks @ArtOsi for your quick reply...

Comment: Actually I want the Null value in the database, so for this should I need to change anything here or change in Database part . @ArtOsi

Comment: Can you please help me by giving the code for this ? @Brainfeeder

Answer (score 2):

All data from form submit is available as string (or array of strings). So empty field is represented by empty string. If you want to change it to `null` you should use [`default`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDefaultValueValidator) validator, which will change empty fields to specified value:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        // ...
        ['confirmation_dt', 'default', 'value' => null],
    ];
}
```

Comment: @KumarSatya In your model.

Comment: array('confirmation_dt', 'default', 'setOnEmpty' => true, 'value' => null),

Comment: When I'm trying entered the null value into database, yii entered   1970-01-01 to my database. I'm using MySQL db. Give me solution for this. @rob006

Comment: @KumarSatya Are you sure that you're not doing any other conversion before save and allow `null` in date column?

Comment: I just change the required field for that, that's all @rob006